Couldn't Fetch Artifact id of an uploaded artifact
I have two private repository A and B and I Am trying to download artifact from repo A to B for which I am using REST API to fetch Artifact ID But some how I am not able to see the id
curl -L 
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer " 
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" 
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/artifacts
-o artifact.json
I have used more artifact.json command to read content inside it but it isn't showing output neither throwing any error. I have already tried several command like cat and jq
I have used below command after giving up on fetching the id. It worked but the artifact format was url and that's why I was unable to unzip it.
curL -u ${{secrets.PAT_TOKEN}} 
-L -o myartifact.zip 
https:// api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/${{github.run_id}}artifacts/zip
Please help me with this I've been pulling my hairs over this for quite a few days now. Please share what has worked for you.
Edit: Adding workflow
jobs:
build:
runs_on: [self-hosted]
steps:
 - name: Checkout code
   uses: actions/checkout@v2

 - name: JDK 11 setup
   uses: actions/setup-java@v2
   with:
     java-version: '11'
     distribution: 'zulu'                   
 - name: Download artifact
   run: |
    curL -u ${{secrets.PAT_TOKEN}} \
    -L -o myartifact.zip \
     https:// api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/${{github.run_id}}artifacts/zip
  - name: View artifact
    run: file myartifact.zip  #gave output that it's an url

  - name: Artifact id  #tried fetching to use it instead of runid
    run: |
     curl -L
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "
     -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
     https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/artifacts -o artifact.json
   
   - name: View artifact file
     run: | 
      file artifact.json  #gave o/p that file is empty
      
 


can you share your full workflows?

@ShaykiAbramczyk Added the workflow . Please have a look now

why not use this? https://github.com/actions/download-artifact

Actually actions/download-arrtifact@v3 does not support downloading in a workflow in different repository and v4 is not supported on GHES. I'm now able to get the artifact id just need to add shell: bash before run:
